# How to create phonegap build for ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

http://build.phonegap.com/
We are creating ios build using phonegap. We have uploaded certificate p12 & profisional profile but error display 
Error - Unable to import Certificate - You can fix this here.

Any help me.

Comment: Did you follow the link on the word *here*?

Comment: You have to follow the instructions from Apple exactly. Don't worry, you'll get it eventually. I recommend re-reading the instructions here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html

Comment: Be specific about your issue, will able to help you out then.